# Who can give me a main program for this code from the documentation of mark?

Tags: c++, c, cuda, parallel-processing, gpu

I have here the codes (parallel reduction) that mark harris documented. I am new in cuda programming and I don't know how can I make the main program for this code. Please help me, thank you.

HERE IS THE CODE:

```
template <unsigned int blockSize>
__global__ voidreduce6(int *g_idata, int *g_odata, unsigned int n)
{
extern __shared__ int sdata[];
unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*(blockSize*2) + tid;
unsigned int gridSize = blockSize*2*gridDim.x;
sdata[tid] = 0;
do{sdata[tid] += g_idata[i] + g_idata[i+blockSize]; i += gridSize; } while (i < n);
__syncthreads();
if (blockSize >= 512) {if(tid<256) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 256]; } __syncthreads(); }
if (blockSize >= 256) {if(tid<128) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 128]; } __syncthreads(); }
if (blockSize >= 128) {if(tid< 64) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 64]; } __syncthreads(); }
if (tid < 32){
if (blockSize >= 64) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 32];
if (blockSize >= 32) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 16];
if (blockSize >= 16) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 8];
if (blockSize >= 8) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 4];
if (blockSize >= 4) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 2];
if (blockSize >= 2) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 1];
}
if (tid == 0) g_odata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the CUDA Toolkit where all the nice CUDA samples are?

Answer (score 1):

A complete example code using this kernel is given in the [CUDA sample codes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-parallel-reduction).

Refer to the file reduction_kernel.cu.  The wrapper function for the kernel launch will select a kernel based on the particular reduction method, and the kernels are also templated for threadblock size:

```
        case 6:
        default:
            if (isPow2(size))
            {
                switch (threads)
                {
                    case 512:
                        reduce6<T, 512, true><<< dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize >>>(d_idata, d_odata, size);
                        break;

                    case 256:
                        reduce6<T, 256, true><<< dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize >>>(d_idata, d_odata, size);
                        break;

                    case 128:
                        reduce6<T, 128, true><<< dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize >>>(d_idata, d_odata, size);
                        break;

                    case 64:
                        reduce6<T,  64, true><<< dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize >>>(d_idata, d_odata, size);
                        break;

                    case 32:
                        reduce6<T,  32, true><<< dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize >>>(d_idata, d_odata, size);
                        break;

                    case 16:
                        reduce6<T,  16, true><<< dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize >>>(d_idata, d_odata, size);
                        break;

                    case  8:
                        reduce6<T,   8, true><<< dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize >>>(d_idata, d_odata, size);
                        break;

                    case  4:
                        reduce6<T,   4, true><<< dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize >>>(d_idata, d_odata, size);
                        break;

                    case  2:
                        reduce6<T,   2, true><<< dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize >>>(d_idata, d_odata, size);
                        break;

                    case  1:
                        reduce6<T,   1, true><<< dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize >>>(d_idata, d_odata, size);
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                switch (threads)
                {
                    case 512:
                        reduce6<T, 512, false><<< dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize >>>(d_idata, d_odata, size);
                        break;

                    case 256:
                        reduce6<T, 256, false><<< dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize >>>(d_idata, d_odata, size);
                        break;

                    case 128:
                        reduce6<T, 128, false><<< dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize >>>(d_idata, d_odata, size);
                        break;

                    case 64:
                        reduce6<T,  64, false><<< dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize >>>(d_idata, d_odata, size);
                        break;

                    case 32:
                        reduce6<T,  32, false><<< dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize >>>(d_idata, d_odata, size);
                        break;

                    case 16:
                        reduce6<T,  16, false><<< dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize >>>(d_idata, d_odata, size);
                        break;

                    case  8:
                        reduce6<T,   8, false><<< dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize >>>(d_idata, d_odata, size);
                        break;

                    case  4:
                        reduce6<T,   4, false><<< dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize >>>(d_idata, d_odata, size);
                        break;

                    case  2:
                        reduce6<T,   2, false><<< dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize >>>(d_idata, d_odata, size);
                        break;

                    case  1:
                        reduce6<T,   1, false><<< dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize >>>(d_idata, d_odata, size);
                        break;
                }
            }

            break;
    }
}

// Instantiate the reduction function for 3 types
template void
reduce<int>(int size, int threads, int blocks,
            int whichKernel, int *d_idata, int *d_odata);

template void
reduce<float>(int size, int threads, int blocks,
              int whichKernel, float *d_idata, float *d_odata);

template void
reduce<double>(int size, int threads, int blocks,
               int whichKernel, double *d_idata, double *d_odata);
```

Comment: for what is this code? Is this for the main function? @robert crovella

Comment: No, it's not the main function.  It's a portion of the code that calls "Mark's code" - the wrapper function for the kernel launch.  There is too much code in the CUDA sample for me to post here, but you can easily review it yourself.  I have given you the link to it.